# How to read list of query params

Tags: postgresql, go, url

I have a method that takes a list of userIDs and return a list of users' details.

```
func ListUser(userIDs []interface{}) (users []User, err error) {
    // query on DB based on userID and return list of users
    return users, nil
}
```

Now I want to expose an API endpoint for it. So, I am trying to get the userIDs from my URL.

```
func ListUserProfile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // I know I can get the single value using 
         //r.URL.Query().Get("user-id")

    // but here List user takes []interface{} as a argument
    users, err := users.ListUser(userIDs)
}
```

Is there have any way I can get the list of userIDS from my URL.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But it can not read multiple ids from URL: domain_host/user/profile/details/list?user-ids=97&user-ids=1&user-ids=15

Comment: Stop using `interface{}` would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the form and copy the `[]string` in the form to an `[]interface{}`. The Go FAQ [explains why copy is required](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface).

```
r.ParseForm()
userIDs := make([]interface{}, len(r.Form["user-id"]))
for i, s := range r.Form["user-id"] {
   userIDs[i] = s
}

users, err := users.ListUser(userIDs)
```

(The question and a comment disagree on the name of the query parameter. Adjust the code in the answer to match the actual name.)